Remote Desktop - Authentication
I'm connecting to Ubuntu from a Mac using Microsoft Remote Desktop. The machine I am connecting to has no monitor or keyboard, and every time I restart it, the authentication password changes, so I can't connect anymore. Why is the password changing with every restart, and is there a way to correct this?

The password is stored in the keyring, unless you set an empty password to the keyring this is not possible (short of manually unlocking the keyring on the machine... Which obviously isn't feasible in case of RDP)

As to why it's changing: it's not really "changing", the password you set after unlocking the keyring persists in the keyring, however if this isn't accessible a random one is generated.

Thanks for the quick reply. So how do I set a permanent password or how do I prevent this from happening?

You can set the keyring's password to an empty password (obviously this has some security implication as it leaves all your passwords stored in plain text in your home folder), if you search "keyring" between your apps it should bring up the "Password and keyring" application, then on the left hand side you should have a list of keyrings, including "Login". Right click on it and select "Change password", enter your old password and then hit enter twice so to have the new password be an empty string.

Confirm and reboot, after reboot you should see your password for RDP altready unlocked in the settings

Perfect, it works! Just save me the work of reattaching a monitor, keyboard, and mouse every time I restart it! THANKS

You're welcome!

The problem is that once you reboot, even though you user is auto-logged into the GNOME session, the keyring, that holds the RDP password you previously set, is locked.
When the keyring is locked, a random password to access the RDP server is generated, which you can see by digging into the settings.
Short of being around the machine (which I guess wouldn't be feasible since you're trying to log in via RDP) and manually unlocking the keyring, I think the only solution would be to set your keyring password to an empty string, which will remove the need of unlocking it (with the adverse effect of leaving your keyring's password unencrypted).
If having your keyring's password unencrypted is not a concern (it might not be, depending on your use case), you can do the following:

Open seahorse (either search it on the dashboard or run it from the terminal)
On the left-hand side, below the "Passwords" section, right click on "Login" and click on "Change password"
Enter your current keyring password (most likely your user's password)
Hit ENTER 3 times
Reboot. From now on the keyring will be accessible right away without the need of unlocking it, and you'll be able to login to the RDP server using the previously stored password

